# Add dynamic link from an object in React

Tags: reactjs, object, hyperlink

I'm new to React and I'm trying to insert a Link in a React Component. I made an object, and each item contains an external link. This the object :

```js
export const myList =
[
    {
        "id":"P1",
        "title":"Title1",
        "description":"The first description",
        "link":"https://random-link.io",
        "cover":require("../img/myImg1.webp")
    },
 
    {
        "id":"P2",
        "title":"Title2",
        "description":"The second description",
        "link":"https://random-link2.io",
        "cover":require("../img/my2ndImg.webp")
    },
    ... 
];
```

The main idea is to create pages for each item of the list, and a link to an external page to see more information.

I tried to do this :

```js
function Page() {
   
    const id = useParams();
    const pageList = myList.find(list => list.id === id.id);


    return(
        <>
            {
                pageList ? (
                    <div className="Page">
                        <img className="ListCover" src={pageList?.cover} alt={pageList?.title}/>
                      
                            <div className="information-list">
                                <span className="title-list">{pageList?.title}</span>
                              
                                                   
                        </div>
                        <div className="description-list">
                            <Dropdown titre="Description" description={pageList?.description} link={pageList?.link} />
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : <Navigate replace to="/404"/>
            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Page;
```

In the Dropdown component, I made this :

```js
function Dropdown({title, description, link}) {
    
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return(
        <div className="dropdown" id={`dropdown-${title}`}>
            <div className="header-dropdown">
                <div className="title-dropdown">{title}</div>
                <span className={`arrow-dropdown ${open}`} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                    <img src={arrow} alt="Open it"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            {
                /* if dropdown is TRUE then it show the description */
                open && <div className="description-dropdown">{description}
                <a href={{pathname:{link}}} rel="noreferrer"> See more</a> </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

The problem is that the link sends me to : http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]; with another method I got http://localhost:3000/myProjet/https://random-link.io

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only issue in your code is that you are trying to use an object as the parameter for `href` which takes a string, try to just put link in there and it should work. it should look like:

```
<a href={link} rel='noreferrer'>
```